# Regex match groups of digits followed or not by spaces, words

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match with regex:

```
101.6 x 101.6 mm
150   x      150 mm
490 x 100 x 380 mm
490 x 100 x 380 x 430 mm
280mm x 260 mm
```

and extract the value(digits) as separate groups.
I'm using:

```
^(?P<value>[-\.\d]+)([\s]*)([x]+)
```

but, I want something that doesn't care about how many times the digits appear.

What I want to obtain as groups:

```
101.6, 101.6, mm
150, 150, mm
490, 100, 380, mm
490, 100, 380, 430, mm
280, 260, mm
```

I know, can be done with split as it is, but besides the examples above, I have also other expressions that contains "x" and in there case I don't want to split.

Comment: You can use something like `-?\d+(?:.\d+)*(?:\s*mm)?(?:\s+x\s+-?\d+(?:.\d+)*(?:\s*mm)?)*` and then split with `\s+x\s+` to get separate values. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oEvBlv/2). To get them all at once with a single match, you will need PyPi regex module.

Comment: can you provide some examples of the output you would expect to see given those examples above? edge-cases would be helpful too

Comment: Just do `\d*\.?\d+` and loop through the results.

Comment: A simple pattern that detects numbers regardless of the number of digits is:` r"([-]?\d+\.?\d*)"`  Handles ints and floats.

Comment: Can you add what the match you want to get from your example

Answer (score 1):

Given that all the strings in the example data end with `mm` and `mm` might also optionally occur after a digit, you could match an optional occurrence and use a positive lookahead to assert that  the string also ends with `mm` and that what comes in between are to only allowed parts.

If you want to match multiple spaces, you could use `[ ]+` with the brackets in this case for clarity. If there can be more kinds of whitspaces except a newline you could use `[^\S\r\n]*` instead.

Based on multiple spaces, you might use

```
\b(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?: *mm)?(?=(?: +x +\d+(?:\.\d+)?)* mm\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DoFfF9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/a9RueV)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\b(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?: *mm)?(?=(?: +x +\d+(?:\.\d+)?)* mm\b)"

test_str = ("101.6 x 101.6 mm\n"
    "150   x      150 mm\n"
    "490 x 100 x 380 mm\n"
    "490 x 100 x 380 x 430 mm\n"
    "280mm x 260 mm")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['101.6', '101.6', '150', '150', '490', '100', '380', '490', '100', '380', '430', '280', '260']
```